# How to bind key to unexposed plugin function?

Tags: vim, plugins, key-bindings

I am using [Commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary). It defines the following keybindings:

```
command! -range -bar Commentary call s:go(<line1>,<line2>)
xnoremap <expr>   <Plug>Commentary     <SID>go()
nnoremap <expr>   <Plug>Commentary     <SID>go()
nnoremap <expr>   <Plug>CommentaryLine <SID>go() . '_'
onoremap <silent> <Plug>Commentary        :<C-U>call <SID>textobject(get(v:, 'operator', '') ==# 'c')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>ChangeCommentary c:<C-U>call <SID>textobject(1)<CR>
nmap <silent> <Plug>CommentaryUndo :echoerr "Change your <Plug>CommentaryUndo map to <Plug>Commentary<Plug>Commentary"<CR>

if !hasmapto('<Plug>Commentary') || maparg('gc','n') ==# ''
  xmap gc  <Plug>Commentary
  nmap gc  <Plug>Commentary
  omap gc  <Plug>Commentary

  nmap gcc <Plug>CommentaryLine " <-------------------- I WANT TO REBIND THIS

  if maparg('c','n') ==# '' && !exists('v:operator')
    nmap cgc <Plug>ChangeCommentary
  endif
  nmap gcu <Plug>Commentary<Plug>Commentary
endif
```

To keep some of my muscle memory compatible between Vim and Emacs I want to map `gcc` to `M-;`, as that is my Emacs binding for comment toggle. But I can't figure out how to do that, as `CommentaryLine` is not exposed. Meaning I cannot call it with `:` from the "minibuffer" (name for that in Vim?).

How can such unexposed functions, that are only accessible to the user through predefined key bindings, be mapped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Plug" mappings let plugin authors create as many mapping as they want for their plugin without interfering with the user's own mappings:

- the plugin exposes a `<Plug>Whatever` that's not mapped to any key,
- the user can map that plug mapping to whatever key or key sequence he wants.

In this case, the author creates a number of plug mappings (`<Plug>CommentaryLine`, `<Plug>Commentary`, etc.) and maps them to harmless key sequences (`gc`, `gcc`, etc. that don't do anything in Vim by default) after checking if they are not already mapped to something else.

> But I can't figure out how to do that, as `CommentaryLine` is not exposed. Meaning I cannot call it with `:` from the "minibuffer" (name for that in Vim?).

Well, there's no `CommentaryLine` command or function to begin with so you will have a hard time finding it exposed anywhere or calling it from the command-line (that's the name of your "minibuffer").

> How can such unexposed functions, that are only accessible to the user through predefined key bindings, be mapped?

Again, `CommentaryLine` is worse than unexposed; it's non-existing!

> ```
> nmap gcc <Plug>CommentaryLine " <-------------------- I WANT TO REBIND THIS
> ```

Did you try the following?

```
nmap <key> <Plug>CommentaryLine
```

See `:help <Plug>`.